# I get "missing number, treated as zero" error with no reason I can see

Tags: errors

The following test code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

[DWP (1981), Heim \& Kratzer (1990)] \\ [[`vi is mortal']]g= 1 iff [[`mortal']] g([[vi]]g) \\ [[`mortal'] ]g([[vi]]g) iff $\lambda$x.mortal(x)(g(vi))

\end{document}
```

generates this error message:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
[
l.6 ... Heim \& Kratzer (1990)] \\ [[`vi is mortal']
                                                  ]g= 1 iff [[`mortal']] g([...

?
```

I have no idea why. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What kind of output do you extect exactly?

Comment: I want the pseudo-code split over 3 lines. This is actually a quote so I want to change it as little as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by the input pattern `\\ [...]`, which matches the usage of `\\[<dimen>]`. By historical reasons, in syntax `\\[<dimen>]`, spaces are allowed (aka ignored) before `[`.

You can use `\\\relax` as a workaround.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

[DWP (1981), Heim \& Kratzer (1990)] \\\relax
[[`vi is mortal']]g= 1 iff [[`mortal']] g([[vi]]g) \\\relax
[[`mortal'] ]g([[vi]]g) iff $\lambda$x.mortal(x)(g(vi))

\end{document}
```

PS: you might need some verbatim environments or algorithm packages to typeset the pseudocode.